# Unable to "Import Reports" with SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting, ms-access-2010

I'm attempting to use the "Import Reports - Access" feature as discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156508.aspx

Unfortunately on my system I'm not getting the "Import Reports" option (either through the Project menu or through a right click on the project in the Solution Explorer).

My specifications:
Visual Studio 2010
Access 2010
SQL Server 2008 R2 (Reporting Services installed)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install SQL Server 2008 R2 `Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)`. This is part of SQL Server 2008 R2 Client Tools. Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support SSRS projects yet. Screenshot #**1** shows the option `Import Reports` --> `Microsoft Access...` available in the SQL Server 2008 R2 BIDS, which is currently part of Visual Studio 2008 IDE.

Please refer the following link for more details:

[**SSRS Project in Visual Studio 2010**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/78bd6eb6-9d14-48e2-80eb-8c8e66b52534)

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]